# My svn status shows "C". How do I fix that?

Tags: svn, conflict

Here is my bash command prompt:

```
-bash-4.1$ svn st
 C      .
C       my_sysconfig.ini
```

The `C` means conflict, right? I would like to use the `mf` (`mine-full`) command on it to just accept my version of the file. How do I do that?

Also, does anybody know what the `.` is? Is this the `.svn` folder? If it is, why would this show up on my `svn status`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `C` is for conflict. You want:

```
svn resolve --accept mine-full my_sysconfig.ini
```

The `.` refers to the current directory, and the fact that the C for that entry is in the second column means that it's a conflict on metadata/properties for the current directory.  E.g. this could be a conflict in svn:mergeinfo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to resolve the conflict. Depends on your svn and the tools you use, you may have the following options:

```
$ svn update
Updating '.':
Conflict discovered in 'foo.c'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: p
C    foo.c
```

if you want to accept your changes you can use the following svn command.

```
svn resolve --accept mine-full foo.c
```